# Replacing an XML node with Anti-XML

Tags: xml, scala, anti-xml

I am struggling to replace a XML element with another one using the library anti-xml. For instance, I have:

```
<root>
  <sub>
    <keep />
    <replace />
    <keeptoo />
  </sub>
</root>
```

and the fragment:

```
<inserted key="value">
  <foo>foo</foo>
  <bar>bar</bar>
</inserted>
```

I would like to produce:

```
<root>
  <sub>
    <keep />
    <inserted key="value">
      <foo>foo</foo>
      <bar>bar</bar>
    </inserted>      
    <keeptoo />
  </sub>
</root>
```

**Note:** The order of `<sub>` children must be conserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we define the root document :

```
val root = 
<root>
  <sub>
    <keep />
    <replace />
    <keeptoo />
  </sub>
</root>.convert

val inserted =
  <inserted key="value">
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
 </inserted>.convert
```

then we get the  element :

```
val replace = root \\ 'replace
```

and finally we get the xml with updated `<replace/>` node :

```
replace.updated(0, inserted).unselect
```

if we get multiple `<replace/>` nodes, we will be able to iterate over `replace` to update each node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea how I can replace the `<replace>` element by a list of several nodes ?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible but I'm not an antixml expert. Could you consider to have `<replaceA>`, `<replaceB>` ... and to replace them individually ?

Comment: No, because I don't know in advance how many nodes I should add. I use another approach now, but I will fill another question about it, if I meet the problem again.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace selected elements with several nodes using `flatMap`,  e.g. `replace.flatMap(_ => someListOfNodes).unselect`

(Sorry for making it a separate answer, it appears that I can't comment on existing ones.)